# How to fix 'Cannot read property 'Username' of null'

Tags: angular

i want to push new user to users array but it give me an error
the error is "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Username' of null"

i think it cannot subscribe to the new data added. but when i refresh my browser the data i entered was save in the database and will appear in the table.

please help me. i'm new to angular

this is the service user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../classes/user';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserService {

  private uri = 'http://localhost:3000/api/users';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  addUser(username: string, password: string, type: string): Observable<User>{
    return this.http.post<User>(this.uri, {username, password, type}, httpOptions);
  }


  getUsers(): Observable<User[]>{
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.uri);
  }

  deleteUser(userid: number): Observable<User>{
    return this.http.delete<User>(`${this.uri}/${userid}`, httpOptions);
  }


}
```

this the component users.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import { User } from '../../classes/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  users: User[];

  constructor(private userservice: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  addUser(username: string, password: string, type: string): void {
    this.userservice.addUser(username,password,type).subscribe(data => {
      this.users.push(data);
    });
  }


  getUsers(): void {
    this.userservice.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data;
    });
  }

  deleteUser(userid: number, index): void {
    this.users.splice(index, 1);
    this.userservice.deleteUser(userid).subscribe();
  }


}
```

this is the view users.component.html

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addusermodal">Add new</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm">

    <thead>
        <tr class="table-default">
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index;">
            <td>{{ user.Username }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.Password }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.Type }}</td>
            <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editusermodal" (click)="getUser(user.UserID)">Edit</button>&nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="deleteUser(user.UserID, i)">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>

</div>

<!-- add user modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addusermodal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <form>
              <!-- Modal Header -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add user</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>

              <!-- Modal body -->
              <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" name="username" #username>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password" #password>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="type">Type</label>
                              <select  class="form-control" id="type" name="type" #type>
                                  <option>User</option>
                                  <option>Admin</option>
                              </select>
                          </div>

                    </div>




              <!-- Modal footer -->
              <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addUser(username.value, password.value, type.value)">Save</button>
              </div>

            </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Debug the return data. Something tells me it does not return data at all. Creating new entities via a rest service might only return a header pointing to the location of the new data.

Comment: can you log what's returned from server when y add user?

Comment: Hi, if the refresh works, it seems that GET Users is OK, but if after a POST you get the error, seems that an item of your Array is undefined.
You can try adding to your HTTP Options `observe body`, cause I think that the default is `observe response`, which would contain status code, a lot of other stuff and would not be deseralized to a User object.

Comment: change user.Username to user?.Username and make sure API return data

Comment: @JoãoGhignatti the error is after post. how to do observe body?

Comment: @onik it returns null

Comment: than that's the problem you are adding null value into the users array, and when you loop it it is null either, return newly added user from server, or after response just call getUsers() again

Comment: @HienNguyen the api insert i tested it in postman. the error is when adding it cannot subscribe. the push data is empty

Comment: @onik but why it saves to the database the new data i entered. the problem is the subscribe data is null. please help. where is the error. its been 2 days and i still cant solve it.

Comment: Can you show the complete post request including response header and response body?

Comment: @MathiasF UsersComponent.html:21 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Username' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (UsersComponent.html:21)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:23937)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23312)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23511)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23308)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)

Comment: I meant the  log of the http traffic (like from fiddler or f12 tools)

Answer (score 0):

component users.component.ts

you have to initialize the variable users:

**Solution:**

```
users: User[];
```

for

```
 users: User[] = [];
```

**Why?:**

When you use: [] you are only indicating the type of data, but not initializing it

Comment: @Jophil put a console.log of data inside of this.userservice.addUser subscription and tell me the result, please

Comment: it returns null

Comment: addUser(username: string, password: string, type: string): Observable<User>{
    return this.http.post<User>(this.uri, {username, password, type}, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      map(data => data),
      tap(data => console.log("new", data)),
    );
  }

Comment: @Jophil check your response from server, you are pushing null to users array and when you try to read the property Username of null, you get the error

Comment: userController.insert_user = ((req, res, next) => {

    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;
    let type = req.body.type;
   
    bcrypt.hash(password,10, (err, hash) => {
        userModel.insertUser([username, hash, type], (users) => {
            res.send(users);
        });
    });

});

Comment: can you please check, im also new to node

Comment: userModel.insertUser = ((username, password, type , result) => {
    db.query('INSERT INTO tblusers SET Username = ? , Password = ?, Type = ?', username, password, type, (err, res) => {
        result('added successfully');
    });
});

Comment: @Jophil using network developer tools  of your browser, you get the user?

Comment: i use postman..the data was added but i dont have a response json data. i think i get it. i will try

Comment: @Jophil The error is that, I can not help you much with node, apparently your code is correct

Comment: thanks daniel. i get it now..the error is in my server i did not set a response data after post request

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest exposing an Observable for the Users[] in your Service and setting it in your users.component.ts. Then you can subscribe to it in your component.html with the async pipe.

Short example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../classes/user';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserService {

  private uri = 'http://localhost:3000/api/users';
  private users: Users[] = [];
  private usersSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>(this.users);
  users$: Observable<User[]> = this.usersSubject.asObservable();
}
```

You then fetch data from your api and call .next() with the data on users$.

In your users.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import { User } from '../../classes/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  users$: Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(private userservice: UserService) { 
      this.users$ = userservice.users$;
  }
```

Then by making use of the async pipe for subscribing to the observable:

```
<div *ngIf="users$ | async as users">
<tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index;">
            <td>{{ user.Username }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.Password }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.Type }}</td>
            <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editusermodal" (click)="getUser(user.UserID)">Edit</button>&nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="deleteUser(user.UserID, i)">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
</div>
```

Hope it pushes you in the right direction.

Comment: my code works before but now i don't know whats going on. can you check my code where did it go wrong. it cannot subscribe but the data i entered was save in the database. when i refresh my browser the new data was added in the table. the error is in this.users.push(data). when i log the data it returns null. why it cannot subscribe

Comment: I think Daniel in the above answer is right and the problem is in your Server-Code because you return null. You should debug your node-code and see what`s wrong exactly.

Answer (score 0):

First please check via Postman or another platform whether your endpoint works and is returning the proper User object.

On your service you have

```
return this.http.post<User>(this.uri, {username, password, type}, httpOptions);
```

Where your `httpOptions` is

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};
```

If you enter the code for `http.post` you'll notice that the options param can accept a property called `observe` and you'll have cases where it is `body` and cases where it is `response`.

The `observe: response` property will give you something like
[image]
where the body would be your User object, but it'd come along with status code, headers, etc.

So, if you subscribe to that Http call, you'd have to access

```
.subscribe(data => {
  this.users.push(data.body);
}
```

On the other hand, if you change your options to

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
  observe: 'body'
};
```

and subscribe to that Http call, your `data` (inside subscribe) would be the `body`, so, directly your User object.